# Python: How to remove rows from a data_frame based on a list variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list object called `equipment = ['helmet', 'shoes', 'jacket']` and I have a `DataFrame()`, which was initially an excel spreadsheet

| name | age | jacket | shoes | house |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| steve |  | x |  | x |
| abby |  |  | x |  |
| greg |  |  | x | x |

I want to make a function that takes in a data_frame and a list and removes all columns that aren't mentioned in the list. So the previous table would look like this:

| jacket | shoes | house |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x |  | x |
|  | x |  |
|  | x | x |

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think the pictures say "house" where the equipment list says "helmet"?

Answer (score 1):

Good place to use Python sets. Make a set of all labels, a set of the ones you want to keep, then the set difference is the ones you want to drop. Drop them.

```py
# setup -- your code has already done this
import pandas as pd
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'age', 'jacket', 'shoes', 'house'])
equipment = ['jacket', 'shoes', 'house']

# relevant code
all_labels = set(data_frame.columns)
drop_labels = all_labels - set(equipment)
df = data_frame.drop(drop_labels, axis=1)  # axis=1 because we drop columns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.loc to achieve what you expect:

```
df.loc[:, [x for x in list(df.columns.values) if x in equipment]]
```

":" means that you want to take all rows. For columns you can use a list comprehension, to select all columns from a dataframe which also appear on your list.

Comment: Please void code-only answers. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers